Generous Banker
You are at the bank and it is your lucky day. The banker is going pick random positive integer and you are too. You are both allowed to determine the probability distribution on the positive integers that you select from. If you and the banker select the same value, say $n$, you receive $n^2$ dollars. Otherwise, you receive nothing. Neither party knows the distribution the other selected. Assuming optimal strategy from both parties, what is your expected payout from this game?
here's what I've done :
Call our strategy $p_i$ and banker's strategy $q_i$, expected-payoff = $\sum \limits_{i\geq 1} i^2 p_i q_i $
then if we choose our strategy such that $i^2 p_i =$ constant then our payoff is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ regardless of banker's strategy, and this indeed is the answer
but I am unable to prove this is optimal, any help is appreciated. Thanks

If we and the bank select identical probabilities $p_i = q_i = \frac6{\pi^2i^2}$, then the expectation is $\frac6{\pi^2}$ as the OP points out. I believe it's enough to show that:

if we choose a different strategy, then the banker has a strategy that yields an expectation that's less than $\frac6{\pi^2}$;
if the banker chooses a different strategy, then we have a strategy that yields an expectation that's more than $\frac6{\pi^2}$.

For #1, any different strategy we choose will have $p_j < \frac6{\pi^2j^2}$ for some $j$, and the banker could just choose $j$ with probability $1$ to yield the lower expectation $j^2p_j$. Similarly for #2, any different strategy the banker chooses will have $q_j > \frac6{\pi^2j^2}$ for some $j$, and we could just choose $j$ with probability $1$ to yield the higher expectation $j^2q_j$.

Isn't your argument violating the statement "Neither party knows the distribution the other selected"

@Harsh I worried about that too ... but my interpretation of "optimal strategy" is a strategy whose worst-case expected payoff is at least as good as the worst-case expected payoff of any other strategy. This argument shows that any other strategy has the possibility of a worse expected payoff (if the other player makes a lucky guess?).

yeah makes sense

I am surprised you can explain all this without using the words "Nash Equilibrium" :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium -- which basically translates to conditions 1 & 2 above.  The term "optimal" is often taken to mean Nash Equilibrium, in the sense that neither side can (acting alone) do better.
